# Uknown column in having/where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I am not sure if this error lies within my code or within my MySQL table configuration. - I have tried using `WHERE` and `HAVING` and I have also made the HOSTNAME primary/index key within the table. - Always the same error.

> Unknown column 'HOSTNAME' in 'having/where clause'

Note: HOSTNAME is actually my machine hostname, so that's parsed properly.

The line of code:

```
Dim Query As String = "SELECT `HOSTNAME`, `UPDATED` FROM `" & device_1_table & _
    "` WHERE HOSTNAME = `" & device_1_column & "`"
```

Where do I need to look?

Comment: That code will be vulnerable to Sql Injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: Probably the table and column names are provided by the code, not by a user entry (I hope).

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn the code sets the variables for the "device" names not the user :)

Comment: Still no reason not to do parameters the right way. That will be faster, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that the variable `device_1_column` is set to `HOSTNAME`.  You need single quotes, not back ticks, for string literals.  So change this portion of the code:

```
WHERE HOSTNAME = `" & device_1_column & "`
```

to

```
WHERE HOSTNAME = '" & device_1_column & "'
-----------------^ ----------------------^
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the problem. However I added the back tick because the particular device had a dash '-' in the name and I thought I had to add them to support it.